# Nested Menu Not Working as Expected in Angular 2 App

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, submenu

I'd like to incorporate a nested menu into my Angular 2 app. I was already using an "md-menu", but now I'm like to make it a nested menu. So far however, after adding the relevant code, while the menu shows up, I have to click on each main menu item to get the sub-menu to open up. I'm not sure why this is the case considering, in the Angular Material demo (using the same code as far as I can tell), it works as expected -- meaning, when you scroll over a parent element, the sub-menu appears automatically, appearing just to the right of the root menu (https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#nested-menu).

The only thing I've changed in the code from the Angular Material demo code is that I've used "md" in place of "mat" for all elements, as that's what's necessary for the version of Angular 2/Material I'm using. I get an error if I try and use "mat".

This is my view code:

```
   <md-toolbar>
      <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="animals">
        <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
      </button>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-menu #animals="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="vertebrates">Vertebrates</button>
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="invertebrates">Invertebrates</button>
    </md-menu>

    <md-menu #vertebrates="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="fish">Fishes</button>
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="amphibians">Amphibians</button>
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="reptiles">Reptiles</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Birds</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Mammals</button>
    </md-menu>

    <md-menu #invertebrates="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>Insects</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Molluscs</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Crustaceans</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Corals</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Arachnids</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Velvet worms</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Horseshoe crabs</button>
    </md-menu>

    <md-menu #fish="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>Baikal oilfish</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Bala shark</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Ballan wrasse</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Bamboo shark</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Banded killifish</button>
    </md-menu>

    <md-menu #amphibians="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>Sonoran desert toad</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Western toad</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Arroyo toad</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Yosemite toad</button>
    </md-menu>

    <md-menu #reptiles="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>Banded Day Gecko</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Banded Gila Monster</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Black Tree Monitor</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Blue Spiny Lizard</button>
    </md-menu>
  <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
```

Any idea why this isn't working as expected? Again, I have to scroll over an menu item and then click on it to open the sub-menu, whereas, according to the specs and sample demo, the sub-menu should open automatically upon scrolling over the element. One other note, I also don't see the arrows appear on the parent elements when they are scrolled over; whereas they do appear on the Angular demo (link above).

Comment: What's your version of Angular Material? It's supported from only `2.0.0-beta.10` onwards.

Comment: Ah, then that would explain it. I'm on 2.0.0-beta.2. And I'm not sure if I can go any higher with my current configuration. I will look into it, thanks.